# How to subtract or add two hexadecimal value in java

Tags: java, addition, subtraction, hex

Is there a way of calculating two hexadecimal value without converting it to int?
for example:

```
String sHex = "f7c0";
String bHex = "040000000";
```

Comment: What kind of calculation do you want to do? And why do you need to do it without converting to int?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hexadecimal values are integers - just represented in hex instead of decimal.

Can't you just do this?

```
int sHex = 0xf7c0;
int bHex = 0x040000000;
```

If not, then you actually meant:

```
String sHex = "f7c0";
String bHex = "040000000";
```

In which case, the fastest way to do this is still by converting them to integers, using something like `Integer.parseInt(sHex, 16);`

Comment: `Hexadecimal values are integers`  - not so. This could be bit arrays or exoctic unicode points or anything. Just because `Integers can be written in hexadecimal notation.` does not mean the reverse is also true.

Comment: Ingo - agreed, but didn't want to add further confusion to the post.  A better way to state this is that any hexadecimal value is a numeric value - or can at least be represented as one.  Furthermore, longer hexadecimal values may actually require a long or a BigInteger to represent, for example.

Comment: The reason why i want to do that is: 
I read 4bytes (Byte[4]) from socket.
Sometimes this 4 byte includes 0x040000000 and sometimes 0x080000000. 
to get the real value i need to subtract this 4bytes from  0x040000000 or 0x080000000.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do certain (to be exact: any) calculations with strings that hold representations of hexadecimal values.

An easy example would be checking for equality. For this, you convert both strings to lowercase, strip all leading zeroes and apply the String.equals method.

Other calculations are more difficult. But hey, when I was young, we did *all* calculation with paper and pen or with chalk on the board, hence in principle anything that can be computed even if all data have the form of character strings.