# How can I add two Strings containing hexadecimal-numbers without converting them to int?

Tags: java, hex

I have a hexadecimal number in a String which is too large to convert to int and long and want to add the value of another hexadecimal number.
So let's say I have this number:

```
String hex1 = "0xf27f2029f9c103f77be78b9591c1ab27167858d27d789cd3ea8a270c67ea5d91";
```

And want to add:

```
int hex2 = 0x1;  or  String hex2 = "0x1";
```

I know this question has been asked allready [How to subtract or add two hexadecimal value in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245156/how-to-subtract-or-add-two-hexadecimal-value-in-java) but the answers don't work for me because they all involve conversion to int.

Comment: So convert them to a BigInteger. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: If you **don't** convert the `String` to an integral type, then adding those two `String`(s) will give you `"0xf27f2029f9c103f77be78b9591c1ab27167858d27d789cd3ea8a270c67ea5d910x1"` - which I bet you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex1 = "0xf27f2029f9c103f77be78b9591c1ab27167858d27d789cd3ea8a270c67ea5d91";
        String hex2 = "0x1";
        System.out.println(
                "In decimal: " + new BigInteger(hex1.substring(2), 16).add(new BigInteger(hex2.substring(2), 16)));
        System.out.println("In hexdecimal: "
                + new BigInteger(hex1.substring(2), 16).add(new BigInteger(hex2.substring(2), 16)).toString(16));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
In decimal: 109684320921920394042076832992416841330182602685967688614501993994243850001810
In hexdecimal: f27f2029f9c103f77be78b9591c1ab27167858d27d789cd3ea8a270c67ea5d92
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to:

```
String hex1="0xf27f2029f9c103f77be78b9591c1ab27167858d27d789cd3ea8a270c67ea5d91";
int hex2=0x1;
string hex2="0x1";
```

You need "" for entering a value for string.